# Сравнение двух списков состоящих из массивов

Tags: c#, массивы, список, сравнение

Есть два списка `List<byte[]> list1` и `list2`. Элементы в них могут совпадать. 
Мне нужно получить новый список `list3` в который войдут элементы из `list2`, которых не было в `list1`.

Я пытаюсь реализовать это так, но условие не работает и на выходе список пустой.

```
List<byte[]> list3 = list2.Where(x => !list1.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Реализовал это так, но не горел желанием форы использовать, хотелось бы разобраться почему не работал первый вариант.

```
for (byte i = 0; i < list2.Count; ++i)
    for (byte j = 0; j < list1.Count; ++j)
        {
            if (list2[i].SequenceEqual(list1[j]))
                list3.Add(list2[i]);
        }
```

Comment: как между собой `byte[]` надо сравнить? Вы на выходе хотите получить `List<byte[]>` или `List<byte>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первый вариант не работал потому, что `Contains` сравнивает через `Equals`, а равенство по `Equals` для массивов есть равенство ссылок. А вам ведь нужно `SequenceEqual` вместо этого.

Поэтому можно написать свой вариант `Contains`:

```
x => !list1.Any(y => y.SequenceEqual(x))
```